# JMeter : How to increment 30 sec for 2222 times in a next and once done move to next day

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I have a requirement where I need to create 2 million data for past 3 months from April till July. Based on calculation I need to create 2,222 data every Day. I have a Insert Statement, where I need to pass time Stamp which is perfectly working fine. If I use time shift function for example..__timeShift(yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS,now,-PT2H,,)} it successfully insert the data, but once 2222 loop is complete I don't want to wait for 24 hr based on timeshift..once loop is complete, it should take the next date and again start the loop, can someone help me how to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate each day for the past 3 months using any suitable [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and the following [Groovy](https://groovy-lang.org/) code:

```
def format = 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS'
def now = new Date()
use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) {
    def april = now - 3.month
    april.upto(now) {
        def minus2hours = it - 2.hour
        println(minus2hours.format(format))
        1.upto(2222) {
            //here will be your current loop
        }
    }
}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [Groovy TimeCategory](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/time/TimeCategory.html)
- [Creating and Testing Dates in JMeter - Learn How](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/creating-and-testing-dates-in-jmeter-learn-how)

Comment: thanks let me try...well my question was in 3 months every day I will create 2222 data with almost 2 message/min, this code will create data 2222 data...from 3 month till now.